# Contenido de una Function dentro de un Modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal, bootstrap-3

Compañeros, tengo un codigo que va algo asi:

JAVASCRIPT

```js
function nfpa(){
    var resultado = "";
    resultado += "<div>";
    resultado += "CONTENIDO";
    resultado += "</div>";

document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = resultado;
     
}


function selector() {

    fo = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
    document.getElementById('formula').innerHTML = "<b>"+fo+"</b>";
    document.getElementById('entrada').value = "";
    document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('procedimiento').innerHTML = "";
    productoSeleccionado = producto.find(x => x.n === this.value);
    tipoEl = document.getElementById('tipo');
    if (productoSeleccionado) {
        tipoEl.innerText = (productoSeleccionado.t === 'liq' ?
            'Indique la cantidad de LITROS de' + ' ' + fo + ': ' : 'Indique la cantidad de KILOS de' + ' ' + fo + ': ');
    } else {
        tipoEl.innerText = '';
    }

    tipoproducto = "";
    tipoproducto = productoSeleccionado.t;
    if (tipoproducto == "liq"){
        tipoproducto = " Litros de ";
    }
    else {
        tipoproducto = " Kilos de ";
    }

    var az ='';
    var ro ='';
    var am ='';
    var bl ='';

    az = productoSeleccionado.az;
    ro = productoSeleccionado.ro;
    am = productoSeleccionado.am;
    bl = productoSeleccionado.bl;
    bla = productoSeleccionado.bla;
    
    var azul = ""; 
    var rojo = "";
    var amarillo = "";
    var blanco = "";

var valores = [0,1,2,3,4]; 
    var riesgos = [
    "Sin riesgo",
    "Poco peligroso",
    "Peligroso",
    "Muy peligroso",
    "Mortal"];
    var inflamabilidad = [
    "No se Inflama",
    "Inflama a mas de 93°C",
    "Inflama a partir de 93°C",
    "Inflama a parir de 37°C ",
    "Inflama a parir de 25°C "];
    var reactividad = [
    "Estable",
    "Inestable en Caso de Calentamiento",
    "Inestable en caso de cambio quimico violento",
    "Puede Explotar en caso de choque o calentamiento",
    "Puede explotar subitamente"];
    var riesgoesp = [
        "Oxidante",
        "Corrosivo",
        "Radioactivo",
        "No Usar Agua",
        "Riesgo Biologico",
        "Ninguno"];

valores.forEach(function(elemento) {
    if(az == elemento) 
    azul = "Nivel de Riesgo: ["+elemento+"] " + riesgos[elemento];
    if (ro == elemento)
    rojo = "Inflamabilidad: ["+elemento+"] " + inflamabilidad[elemento];
    if (am == elemento)
    amarillo = "Reactividad: ["+elemento+"] " + reactividad[elemento];
    if (bla == elemento)
    blanco = "Riesgo Especial: " + riesgoesp[elemento];
});

    switch (bla) {
        case 0:
            // Oxidante
            var bl = "OXI";
            break;
        case 1:
            // Corrosivo
            var bl = "COR";
            break;
        case 2:
            // Radioactivo
            var bl = "<img alt= '' src='media/imagen/general/24px_simbolo_riesgo_radiactivo.png'> ";
            break;
        case 3:
            // No Usar Agua
            var bl = "<s>W</s>";
            break;
        case 4:
            // Riesgo Biologico
            var bl = "<img alt= '' src='media/imagen/general/24px_simbolo_riesgo_biologico.png'> ";
            break;
             case 5:
            // Riesgo Biologico
            var bl = "";
            break;
    }


    var rombo = "";
    
    rombo += "<tbody>";
    
    rombo += "<tr>";
    rombo += "<th><b>" + fo.toUpperCase() + "</b><br><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal3' name='NFPA' title='Cargar Explicacion sobre Rombo de Seguridad NFPA' href='#NFPA'><b>Rombo NFPA<b/> " + i + l + " </a><\/th>";
    rombo += "<\/tr>";
    rombo += "<tr>";
    rombo += "<td align=\"left\">";
    rombo += "<div class = \"rombo1\" >";
    rombo += "<div class = \"rombo2\" >";
    rombo += "<p>";
    rombo += "<img alt=\"NFPA 704.svg\" src=\"media\/imagen\/general\/NFPA_704.svg.png\"";
    rombo += "width=\"75\" height=\"75\" srcset=\"media\/imagen\/general\/NFPA_704.svg.png 1.5x, media\/imagen\/general\/NFPA_704.svg.png 2x\"";
    rombo += "data-file-width=\"600\" data-file-height=\"600\">";
    rombo += "<\/p>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<div class = \"rojo\" title=\"" + rojo + "\" \">"+ro+"<\/div>";
    rombo += "<div class = \"azul\" title=\"" + azul + "\">" + az +"<\/div>";
    rombo += "<div class = \"amarillo\" title=\"" + amarillo + "\" >" + am +"<\/div>";
    rombo += "<div class = \"blanco\" title=\"" + blanco + "\" >";
    rombo += "" + bl;
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<\/td>";
    rombo += "<\/tr>";
    rombo += "<\/tbody>";

    
    rombo += "<!-- Modal 3 -->";
    rombo += "<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"myModal3\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"myModalLabel\">";
    rombo += "<div class=\"modal-dialog\" role=\"document\">";
    rombo += "<div class=\"modal-content\">";
    rombo += "<div class=\"modal-header\">";
    rombo += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;<\/span><\/button>";
    rombo += "<h4 class=\"modal-title\" id=\"myModalLabel\">ROMBO NFPA<\/h4>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<div class=\"modal-body\">";

    rombo += "<div id='rombo_nfpa'></div>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<div class=\"modal-footer\">";
    rombo += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Cerrar<\/button>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";
    rombo += "<\/div>";

   
    document.getElementById('nfpa').innerHTML = rombo;
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value = sup;

}
```

Mi consulta es como puedo hacer que cuando haga el llamado al MODAL3 se pueda mostrar el contenido de la funcion nfpa() he intentado con un onload y onclick pero carga en la pag el contenido de nfpa() y no dentro del modal.

Tengo una botonera que carga los contenidos de varias function es decir objetos carga function objetos() extension carga la function extension() pero hay otras function como el ejemplo donde requiero cargar el contenido de nfpa() dentro de un modal para evitar salir del contenido que se le esta dando lectura.

Comment: La tercera linea no deberia de ser: resultado += "<div>";

Comment: Si correctamente.. es que edite todo el valor de resultado al que coloque en el ejemplo.. ya que lo que deseo es que la function se ejecute dentro del modal3